# Hide a paragraph of static block /cms page from wholesale customer group in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.8, static-block

i'm using CMS pages and Static Blocks and would like to hide a text paragraph from showing it to a wholesale group.

is this possible with magento? Kindly help.

Magento 1.8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If,you want to hide a text paragraph from ,then first check `wholesaler is logged` in or not, then  check  `current customer group`  is `wholesaler`.

Here code  add in header.phtml

```
<?php
    if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() and Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId()==2 ){
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("noforid").style.display=none;
    </script>
    /* using jquery*/
     <?php 
    // do not show paragraph
    //Get customer Group name
    $group = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($groupId);
     }
    else{
    ?>
    <?php
    // text paragraph of your
    }
    ?>
```

And put you content `in  a html element` and put `id of element`.Using `java-script hide` the content.

```
<p id="noforid">your text</p>
```

Comment: but i'm talking about a paragraph in the text editor of the CMS pages/Static blocks and NOT the entire page/block.

Here's the paragraph for example: "Welcome to the world of Handloom products. Here are the varieties <hidden> which is shown only to the wholesale users."

Comment: First of all, you cannot check customer data in editor static content.

Comment: If you want hidden the text ,then add my code in header.phtml and  put the Welcome to the world of Handloom product in html element. After that using javasciprt hide and show text

Comment: instead of the jquery, i used css as there was some issue. anyways, you are f**king AWESOME. Thank You so much :)

Comment: up-voted and also have made it as accepted answer. Hope someone else find it useful too. Thanks again :)